When $x^2+qy^2$ does not represent a prime $p$?
Let $p_1,...,p_n$ be positive prime numbers with $p_1<p_2<...<p_n$. Does there exist a prime $q$ such that $p_n<q$ and $p_i\ne x^2+qy^2$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and all $i=1,...,n$?
I have seen in Cox's book, "Primes of the form $X^2+nY^2$ Fermat, Class Field Theory and Complex Multiplication" that the form $x^2+qy^2$ represents infinitely many primes, but I have no idea if, for a given prime $p$, there exists another prime $q$ such that $x^2+qy^2$ does not represent $p$.

Say for sake of simplicity that all the $p_i$'s are odd.
Note that if $x^2+qy^2$ represents $p$ then $y$ is not divisible by $p$, and thus $-q$ is a square modulo $p$.
So let $e_i$ be a integer prime to $p_i$ which is not a square modulo $p_i$.
By CRT, there is an $a$ such that $a \equiv e_i \mod p_i$ for all $i$.
Now by Dirichet's theorem , there is infinitely many primes $q$ such that $q\equiv -a \mod p_1\cdots p_n$.
Such $q$ satisfies $-q\equiv a \equiv e_i \mod p_i$, hence is not a square mod $p_i$, so in particular $x^2+qy^2$ does not represent $p_i$ for all $i$.
